# Publishing JSON data to HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I am excepting an outlook like this:
[Image relating to output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95fDf.png)

What I want to know is how can I create this output without having to write `<p>` again and again using pure JavaScript and JSON, without any JS library.

The JSON data looks like this:

```
[{"id":1,"first_name":"David","food":"Pizza","age":"24"},
{"id":2,"first_name":"Jack","food":"Hamburger","age":"22"},
{"id":3,"first_name":"Harrison","food":"Sweets","age":"8"},.....
```

My HTML body looks like this

```
<body>
</div class="content">
<center>
<p><B>People and their Foods</B></p>
</center>
</div>
</body>
```

Please help me, as I am new to this code world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can loop through your data and dynamically create elements with each iteration and assign them to the main/root div.

```js
// javascript

// pure javascript

//  function to render data
function renderData (data) {
  var root = document.getElementById("root");
  for(var i =0; i<data.length; i++){
    // here you can also create inner loop as well. but following is easier for  you.
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var para1  = document.createElement("P");
    para1.innerText  = "name:" + data[i].first_name;
    div.appendChild(para1);
    var para2  = document.createElement("P");
    para2.innerText  = "food:" + data[i].food;
    div.appendChild(para2);
    var para3  = document.createElement("P");
    para3.innerText  = "age:" + data[i].age;
    div.appendChild(para3);
    root.appendChild(div);
  }
}

// load your json data and then call renderData function
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(); // asynchronous request
httpRequest.open("GET", "local/path/file.json", true);
httpRequest.send();
httpRequest.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
    if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
        // when the request has completed
        var object = JSON.parse(this.response);
        // assuming that in json file data is an attribute
        renderData(object.data);
    }
});
```

```html
<!-- html part -->

<body>
<div class="content">
<center>
<p><b>People and their Foods</b></p>
</center>

<!-- == i have added one div with id root == -->
<div id="root"></div>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: My data is too big and it is in data.json file, how can I call it?

Comment: Also the console is providing me error 'root is null'

Comment: please pay attention I have added a div with id root in HTML.